# Querying DOM elements generated by Aura components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<input lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" 
  id="input-576" 
  type="text" 
  role="combobox" 
  aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-haspopup="listbox" 
  required="" 
  autocomplete="off" 
  name="Rejection_Classification__c" 
  aria-readonly="true" 
  aria-autocomplete="none" 
  aria-owns="dropdown-element-576" 
  class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" 
  aria-controls="dropdown-element-576">
```

I would like to know how does Salesforce prevent access to this DOM element via id. This element is generated by `<lightning:inputField>` pre-built component and is given an id `input-576`.

When I do `document.querySelector('#input-576')` in the console it returns null. Can someone explain why is that so? How does Salesforce *hide* these elements from the DOM? There is no specific reason I would like to use this generally, I just want to know from an educational perspective.

Example calling from console returning null:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aura base components are converted to lightning web components under the hood.

Your `<lightning:inputField>` ends up as the highlighted code line which is owned by a `lightning-combobox` (not part of your screenshot)

For (lightning) web components, [Shadow DOM rules apply](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

Comment: Were aura components always made with the Web Component functionality (even before LWC)?

Comment: No, they were not. I think you querySelector would have worked back or before 2018 when they didn't have web components on the platform yet

Comment: Also, I have just checked via inspector and it doesn't tag the elements as shadow DOM. It's even visible from my screenshot for *lightning-base-combobox*, that is a web component as well yet it doesn't apecify shadow DOM in the inspector. Are you sure shadow DOM is the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's confusing. the #shadow parts don't show for me either. No clue how salesforce does it :)

Comment: I'm asking around for insights/support from Salesforce, Im curious as well.

Comment: Nice, let me know if you find anything out. :)

Comment: I hope it'll end up in an answer over here soon. In the meantime  here's the status quo: Platform/Lex uses synthetic shadow dom (to support older browsers) and #shadow doesn't show up for synthetic shadow dom. Cf. https://mobile.twitter.com/PhilippeOzil/status/1463581124664430595

Comment: From that Twitter Thread, here's how LWC override your query selector on platform: https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/blob/master/packages/%40lwc/synthetic-shadow/src/faux-shadow/element.ts#L365

Comment: Thanks, by the way, do you know anything about the syntax used on line 373?

Comment: I have another bounty on a question regarding the code you linked. If you can do your magic with internal developers again it would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3):

As for your question about how Salesforce does this, it uses what they call the Lightning Locker Service. More specifically, the DOM Access Containment aspect of Locker Service.

From [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm):

> A component can only traverse the DOM and access elements created by a
> component in the same namespace. This behavior prevents the
> anti-pattern of reaching into DOM elements owned by components in
> another namespace.

> Lightning Locker uses the standard JavaScript Proxy object to filter a
> component’s access to underlying JavaScript objects. The Proxy object
> ensures that a component only sees DOM elements created by a component
> in the same namespace.

More information on how the Proxy object is used to contain DOM access can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm

More information on Locker Service in general:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm

Additionally, that id value (input-576) you are querying for is the Global ID for the generated component, and is not guaranteed to be the same beyond the lifetime of the component. Global Ids are useful for debugging purposes, but not for usage within your JavaScript to retrieve the element. (I know you said you weren't actually trying to do this, just for educational purposes, but I thought it would be helpful to add this information for anyone reading along)

What you can do is assign the lightning:inputField a local id using aura:id and use the find() method to retrieve it.

markup:

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="myInput1" />
```

javascript:

```
let input = cmp.find("myInput1");
```

Edit:

To specifically answer the question about how Salesforce "hides" things from the browser console

Lightning Locker also restricts the use of global objects such as Document. When you call `document.querySelector('#input-576')` locker intercepts this and uses SecureDocument instead.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_global_access.htm

They also implement a Synthetic Shadow DOM (with Polyfill for older browser support).

Here is a link to a good overview of how Salesforce leverages the Shadow DOM: https://youtu.be/K5i9zMzVlzM

Comment: While your answer covers pretty much everything when the calling happens inside an Aura Component I have specified in my question why this happens when called from browser console when all of this should be accessible. Editing the question with example.